# Почему background-image не работает? Уже все перепробовал

Tags: html, css

```
<section class="contacts">
          <div
            class="contaсts__intro"
            style="background-image: url(Images/фон.jpg)"
          >
            <div class="container">
              <div class="contacts__window">
                <h2 class="contacts__title"></h2>
                <p class="contacts__info"></p>
                <p class="address__contacts"></p>
                <p class="contacts__time"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Что значит _"не работает"_ и что конкретно пробовали? Уверены что путь к изображению верно указан, нет ли в консоли 404 ошибки и тд? Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqzdI.png ширину и высоту диву задайте, чтоб картинке было где появится, лучше ознакомиться с правилами сайта, чтоб не получать минусы (тк потом накладывается блокировка, если много минусов) качественный вопрос как задать =>  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask